# What likelihood to use to model sample means from a Pareto-like distribution?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, central-limit-theorem, pareto-distribution

Suppose there is a random variable with [Lomax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomax_distribution) (Pareto Type II) [probability density](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lomax.html)

$$
P(x; c) = \frac{c}{(1 + x )^{c + 1}}, \quad x \ge 0, c > 0.
$$

Let's draw n_samples=30000 samples of length sample_len=500 and compute mean in each sample.
For a distribution with finite mean and variance, a distribution of sample means should be close to normal due to a [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).
But for Lomax with $c \le 2$ variance is not finite, and sample means distribution is not normal (see a plot below):

[image: lomax_central_means]

Are there any likelihoods that can be used to model such distribution of central means?

Looks like an [inverse-gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) model can provide a decent fit (see the plot), but is there any theoretical justification for this?
I've seen there is a [generalized central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Generalized_theorem) that applies to a sum of Pareto random variables, but have not seen any simple closed-form expressions for a limiting distribution.

Thanks!

Code to reproduce the plot:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import plotly.graph_objects as go

np.random.seed(7)

c = 1.7
sample_len = 500
n_samples = 30000

exact_dist = stats.lomax(c=c)
samp = exact_dist.rvs(size=(n_samples, sample_len))
means = np.array([x.mean() for x in samp])

clt_like_mean = samp.mean()
clt_like_stdev = means.std() 

invgamma_alpha = (means.mean()**2 / means.std()**2 + 2)
invgamma_beta = means.mean() * (means.mean()**2 / means.std()**2 + 1)
#arbitrary corrections for better fit
invgamma_beta = invgamma_beta / 2
invgamma_loc = 0.7

x = np.linspace(0.001, 30, 10000)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=exact_dist.pdf(x), 
                         mode='lines', line_dash='dash', name='Original Distribution'))
fig.add_vline(exact_dist.mean(), name='Original Distribution Mean')
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=means, histnorm='probability density', name='Sample Means'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=clt_like_mean, scale=clt_like_stdev), 
                         mode='lines', name='CLT-like Normal'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=stats.invgamma.pdf(x, a=invgamma_alpha, loc=invgamma_loc, scale=invgamma_beta), 
                         mode='lines', name='InvGamma'))
fig.update_layout(title='Sample Means Distribution',
                  xaxis_title='x',
                  yaxis_title='Prob Density',
                  hovermode="x",
                  height=550)
fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[0, 5])
fig.show()
```

Comment: The density\* of sums of IID Pareto random variates is discussed in Ramsay, C. M. (2008),  
The Distribution of Sums of I.I.D. Pareto Random Variables with Arbitrary Shape Parameter,  
Communications in Statistics - Theory and Methods, Volume 37, Issue 14, p 2177-2184 (from which an answer to your question could be obtained)  ... but a more useful question would be the frame-challenge ***why take the average at all?***; that's not a good way to summarize the information in a Pareto.  . . . \* (NB do not call it the likelihood)

Comment: I've tried to derive something similar ([Deriving the limiting distribution of a sum of Pareto distributed variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/552589/deriving-the-limiting-distribution-of-a-sum-of-pareto-distributed-variables)) and for $\alpha = 0.5$ it seems to approach a Levy distribution. I guess that for other values $\alpha < 2$ the average of a sample will also approach an alpha-stable function. I stopped at that point, but I guess you could use a [series representation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution#Series_representation) of those distributions.

Comment: Another related question where a sum of Pareto variables occurs: [Expectation of the ratio of sum (XY) and sum(X)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/573398/) In that question a sum of the inverse of uniform variables occurs, which relates to Pareto variables with $\alpha = 1$ and the related limiting distribution is the [Landau distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_distribution).

Comment: Yes, "why take the average at all?" is a valid concern :) Indeed, I have omitted most of the context from the question. Probably I'll try to post a separate question with a more detailed description of my problem. Thanks! @Glen_b

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, Glen_b, thanks for the links! I'll take a look!